# How to call a function from class in wp table list button form

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I try to call a function which generates a pdf based on row ID from wp table list So i have:

```
   public function column_default($item, $column_name)
        {
            switch ($column_name) {
              case "ID":
                return $item[$column_name]
              case "pdf":
                    return '
                        <form method="post" action="' . esc_attr('admin-post.php'). '">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pdf_generate"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $item['ID'] . '"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="PDF"/>
                      </form>';
    }
```

and I'm trying to call a function in another plugin file :

```
add_action( 'admin_post_pdf_generate', 'pdf_generator' );
 function pdf_generator()
{
  //something mpdf
}
```

but each time when I click PDF i see blank page and url is example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php without any action

Comment: Well, the first input should be named `action`, whereas the last input (the submit button) should use another `name`. :)

Comment: I change  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pdf_generate"/> to
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="pdf_generate"/>
and <input type="submit" name="action" value="PDF"/> to
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="PDF"/>
Still blank page

Comment: Your `pdf_generator()` function isn't actually blank like that in your actual code, is it? And what's the structure of your plugin? Your `add_action()` might be called late, so WordPress does not recognize your action.

Comment: my function: https://pastebin.com/4mkLD5g4
when I created this function in class where i create the wp table list it worked, but it displayed a header error and was illegible

Comment: Try something simple in your callback, e.g. add `echo 'it works'; exit;` at the top, just for testing. If you see that output after you submit the form, then your callback is being recognized and executed properly. Otherwise, your other plugin file needs to make sure the callback is registered on time, e.g. try moving the `add_action()` to the root of (i.e. not in any function in) your main plugin file - [example](https://pastebin.com/5vaxGkeR).

Comment: Yes it's working, thank you very much :)